# Trouble posting to many-to-many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post a combination object, which refers to already existing tag objects. Basically I want the tag_id field of the combination to include 2 ids referring to Tag objects.

This is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Combination(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gameround = models.ForeignKey(Gameround, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tag_id = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag_id) or ''
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CombinationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  tag_id = TagWithIdSerializer(many=True, required=False)
  resource_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Resource.objects.all(),
                                                   required=True,
                                                   source='resource',
                                                   write_only=False)
  gameround_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Gameround.objects.all(),
                                                    required=False,
                                                    source='gameround',
                                                    write_only=False)
  user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(),
                                               required=False,
                                               source='user',
                                               write_only=False)

  class Meta:
    model = Combination
    depth = 1
    fields = ('id', 'user_id', 'gameround_id', 'resource_id', 'tag_id', 'created', 'score')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    user = None
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
      user = request.user

    score = 0

    tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag_id')

    combination = Combination(
      user=user,
      gameround=validated_data.get("gameround"),
      resource=validated_data.get("resource"),
      created=datetime.now(),
      score=score
    )
    for tag_object in tag_data:
      combination.set(tag_id=tag_object)
    if len(combination.tag_id) == 2:
      return combination

  def to_representation(self, instance):
    rep = super().to_representation(instance)
    rep['tag_id'] = TagWithIdSerializer(instance.tag_id.all(), many=True).data
    return rep
```

With this I am currently getting an AttributeError : 'Combination' object has no attribute 'set'

If I update this:

```
for tag_object in tag_data:
      combination.set(tag_id=tag_object)
```

Like this:

```
    combination.save()
    for tag_object in tag_data:
      combination.tag_id.add(tag_object)
```

I am now getting the error Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict([('name', 'word'), ('language', 'en')]).

If I add:

```
    combination.save()
    for tag_object in tag_data[0]:
      combination.tag_id.add(tag_object)
```

I get the ValueError Field 'id' expected a number but got 'name'.

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set objects in a ManyToMany field in Django you have to save the object before. Like so

```py
combination.save()

for tag_object in tag_data:
    combination.tag_id.add(tab_object)
```

Comment: This solved the previous problem. Thank you for that! However, now I am getting the error: Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict

Comment: Ok, I Believe its because of tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag_id')
If I remember correct .pop returns a dictionary of.
Try to use something like tag_data[0].
Like
for tag_object in tag_data[0]:

Comment: I have tried this out now and I get the error Field 'id' expected a number but got 'name'.

Comment: What is tag_data[0] is returning ? probably could be something with Tag Serializer.
For creation you dont need to pass a serialzer of this tags objects. 
Try to call direct 'tag_id' in your fields.

Comment: I think somehow it does not see the id in the json I am passing and it just passing the name and language of the tag object for some reason. How do you mean to call it directly in the fields?

Comment: Yes for the test. Just comment the line tag_id = TagWithIdSerializer....

Comment: If I out comment the serializer it doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: I you comment the serializer on tag_id and leave the field in. you just need to pass the Id of an existing object tag on Json.

Comment: If I do this I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Sorry for my late. Intense work this week. Did you solve this problem ?